# Break out of for(ever) loop by resolved Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I hope this is a simple question but I currently can't wrap my head around.

What I want to do is break out of a while loop which contains a delay when a promise gets resolved.

In pseudocode this would look like:

```
while( ! promise.resolved ){
    doSomthing()
    await sleep( 5min )
}
```

The loop *must break instantly after the promise is resolved* and not wait for `sleep` to finish.

`sleep` is currently implemented trivially by `setTimeout` but can be implemented differently.

I would like to have some kind of spatial separation between the awaited promise and sleep to show its working more clearly*) (and because I hope for an elegant solution to learn from).
So what would work **but I don't like** is something like:

```
while( true ){

    doSomething()
    try {
        await Promise.race([promise,rejectAfter(5000)])
        break
    } catch( e ){}
}
```

If you must know:

`doSomething` is sending out status information.

`promise` is waiting for user interaction.

*) Part of the purpose of this code is to show/demonstrate others how things are expect to work. So I'm looking for the clearest solution on this level of implementation.

Comment: Good question. Waiting for solutions.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain you can give the while loop a label and then call the `break label` syntax, e.g. `someLabel: while(true) { ... other code ... break someLabel } `

Comment: Better solution, do not rely on this pattern.

Comment: What do you mean by "*some kind of spatial separation between the awaited promise and sleep*"?

Comment: "*So what would work*" - actually it doesn't quite work; if `promise` is rejected it will continue looping forever.

Comment: @Bergi: I find it hard to explain it in short. "spatial separation" was an attempt boiling it down to put the two parts of code on different places. Imho the code I don't like doesn't tell clearly what is going on. My first pseudocode tells you what is happening even if you never wrote javascript. For second example you have to first search for where the loop is left and know what Promice.race does. Than you have to know about control flow with exceptions. That is why I liked your second approach. It tells what it does.

Comment: @Scheintod Ah, in that case just write a function, name it appropriately and document it nicely. Could even use some fluent API like `const result = await runInterval(doSomething,5000).untilPromiseSettles( someTask() );`. Then you can put either of the possible implementations inside that function, the reader won't care. And yes, controlling the flow of exceptions in asynchronous code is hard :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to wait for the promise result, assuming it is a truthy value<sup>1</sup>:

```
const promise = someTask();
let result = undefined;
while (!result) {
    doSomething();
    result = await Promise.race([
        promise, // resolves to an object
        sleep(5000), // resolves to undefined
    ]);
}
```

<sub>1: and if it isn't, either chain `.then(_ => true)` to the `promise`, or make `sleep` fulfill with a special value that you can distinguish from everything `someTask` might return (like the symbol in Jeff's answer).</sub>

Also works nicely with a `do`-`while` loop, given `result` is always undefined at first:

```
const promise = someTask();
let result = undefined;
do {
    doSomething();
    result = await Promise.race([
        promise, // resolves to an object
        sleep(5000), // resolves to undefined
    ]);
} while (!result);
```

A downside here is that if `doSomething()` throws an exception, the promise is never awaited and might cause an unhandled rejection crash when the task errors.

---

Another approach would be not to use a loop, but an old-school interval:

```
const i = setInterval(doSomething, 5000);
let result;
try {
    result = await someTask();
} finally {
    clearInterval(i);
}
```

A downside here is that `doSomething` is not called immediately but only after 5s for the first time. Also, if `doSomething` throws an exception, it will instantly crash the application. It still might be a good approach if you don't expect `doSomething` to throw (or handle each exception in the `setInterval` callback and expect the "loop" to carry on).

---

The "proper" approach that will forward all exceptions from both `someTask()` and `doSomething()` could look like this:

```
let done = false;
const result = await Promise.race([
    (async() => {
        while (!done) {
            doSomething();
            await sleep(5000)
        }
    })(),
    someTask().finally(() => {
        done = true;
    }),
]);
```

<sub>(Instead of `.finally()`, you can also wrap the `Promise.race` in a `try`-`finally`, like in approach two.)</sub>

The only little disadvantage in comparison to approach two is that `sleep(5000)` will keep running and is not immediately cancelled when `someTask` finishes (even though `result` is immediately available), which might prevent your program from exiting as soon as you want.

Comment: Hi Bergi. The first part is what I didn't want to do. See my comment at VLAZ's answer. I like the keep it simple approach of the second part though.

Comment: @Scheintod If you want clean code that separates the loop out of your main flow, I would suggest to put it into a helper function and do `const result = await runUntilSettled(someTask(), doSomething, 5000)`. Where `runUntilSettled` could be implemented quite like VLAZ' `waitAndDo`.

Comment: Clean code. Totally my thing :) But really. Your second example nails it for me. As "boring" as it is everyone will understand what it does and it has nothing to hide. Doesn't strictly answer my question but you third does somehow. I like your clear style. So if you have more ideas on that topic keep them comming ;)

Answer (score 2):

Minor modification of your idea to make it work better:

```
const sleep = ms =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function waitAndDo(promise) {
  let resolved = false;
  const waitFor = promise
    .then((result) => resolved = true);
    
  while(!resolved) {
    doSomething();
    await Promise.race([waitFor, sleep(5000)]);
  }
}
```

1. The function accepts a promise and will be working until it resolves.
2. The `waitFor` promise will finish after `promise` is fulfilled and `resolved` updated to `true`.
3. The `while` loop can then loop until the `resolved` variable is set to `true`. In that case, the loop will end an execution continues after it.
4. Inside the loop, [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) will ensure that it will stop awaiting as soon as the promise resolves *or* the sleep expires. Whichever comes first.

Therefore, as soon as the promise gets resolve, the `.then()` handler triggers first and updates `resolved`. The `await Promise.race();` will end the waiting after and the `while` loop will not execute again, since `resolved` is now `true`.

Comment: Hi Vlaz. Thank you very much for your effort. What you wrote will work but it is very similar to the code I showed that I don't like to use. I'm looking for some way to separate the tasks of sleeping and listening for some user interaction. Not because it would not work but because of semantic/aesthetic/clearness reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you would just use some sort of interval and kill it when the promise is done.

```js
const updateMessage = (fnc, ms, runInit) => {
  if (runInit) fnc();
  const timer = window.setInterval(fnc, ms);
  return function () {
    console.log('killed');
    timer && window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}

const updateTime = () => {
  document.getElementById("out").textContent = Date.now();
}

const updateEnd = updateMessage(updateTime, 100, true);

new Promise((resolve) => {
  window.setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random()*5000));
}).then(updateEnd);
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @espascarello: Thank you very much for your answer. This one took me the longest to chew on :) I think it is essentially the same Bergi's second one. I like the approach of returning the stop function with the starting of the interval. Definitively something I will put in my toolbag.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to VLAZ's very reasonable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70946141/1426891), you can avoid the separate boolean sentinel by having your sleep function return some kind of unique sentinel return value that indicates the the timeout. [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) is exactly the kind of lightweight, unique object for this use case.

```js
function sleepPromise(ms, resolveWith) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms, resolveWith);
  });
}

const inputPromise = new Promise(
    resolve => document.getElementById("wakeUp").addEventListener("click", resolve));

async function yourFunction() {
  const keepSleeping = Symbol("keep sleeping");
  do {
    /* loop starts here */
    console.log("Sleeping...");
    /* loop ends here */
  } while (await Promise.race([inputPromise, sleepPromise(3000, keepSleeping)]) === keepSleeping);
  console.log("Awake!");
}

yourFunction();
```

```html
<button id="wakeUp">Wake up</button>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thank you very much for your answer. Took me some time to fully understand whats going on (and what a Symbol is... never used that before... but would have needed it two days ago for another thing :) and now I have learnt quite something new.